# Using User Defaults to remember something is hidden or unhidden

Tags: ios, swift4, xcode9, userdefaults

I am using Xcode 9 and swift 4.
How can i get Xcode to remember a button is hidden or a label is hidden, using User Defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set this in defaults and read it anywhere

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isBtnHidden")
```

and set

```
self.button.isHidden = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isBtnHidden")
```

Comment: It works in viewDidLoad but when i put it inside a button in a if statement it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: by default value for key  **isBtnHidden** is false

Comment: In my button i have if button2.isHidden == true i put the code in so when the button becomes hidden i want it to remember that